# how to get tabular query result

Tags: oracle, pivot

I have table that have item (20 item) name and quantity for one piece ( s=1 m=1 L=2 XL=4 )  (fabric need 1m for s size )

in other table have customer demand quantity (s=2000, m=2000, l=2000, xl=2000)

need every item total quantity as per customer required quantity

give me idea how I use the pivot table query for tabular result

how to get size wise item total quantity

thank you for your help as soon as possible

regard

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite clear without sample data and expected result, but here are two options to do it both having "pivoted" number of ordered ITEMS and FABRIC_QUANTITIES needed per item and customer. Hopefuly it would help you:

```sql
WITH      --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    items AS
        ( Select  1 "ITEM_ID", 'Name 1 S' "ITEM_NAME", 'S' "ITEM_SIZE" From Dual Union All
          Select  2, 'Name 1 M',   'M' From Dual Union All
          Select  3, 'Name 1 L',   'L' From Dual Union All
          Select  4, 'Name 1 XL', 'XL' From Dual Union All
          Select  5, 'Name 2 S',   'S' From Dual Union All
          Select  6, 'Name 2 M',   'M' From Dual Union All
          Select  7, 'Name 2 L',   'L' From Dual Union All
          Select  8, 'Name 2 XL', 'XL' From Dual Union All
          Select  9, 'Name 3 S',   'S' From Dual Union All
          Select 10, 'Name 3 M',   'M' From Dual Union All
          Select 11, 'Name 3 L',   'L' From Dual Union All
          Select 12, 'Name 3 XL', 'XL' From Dual 
        ), 
    orders AS
        ( Select 1001 "ORDER_ID",  5 "ITEM_ID", 2000 "QUANTITY", 11 "CUSTOMER_ID" From Dual Union All 
          Select 1001,  2, 2000, 12 From Dual Union All 
          Select 1001, 11, 2000, 11 From Dual Union All 
          Select 1001,  8, 2000, 14 From Dual 
        )
```

```sql
-- Option 1.  -  Case expressions used for pivoting
Select    i.ITEM_ID, i.ITEM_NAME, 
          o.CUSTOMER_ID,
          Case When i.ITEM_SIZE = 'S' Then o.QUANTITY End "SIZE_S_ITEMS",
          Case When i.ITEM_SIZE = 'S' Then o.QUANTITY * 1 End "SIZE_S_FABRIC_QNT",
          Case When i.ITEM_SIZE = 'M' Then o.QUANTITY End "SIZE_M_ITEMS",           
          Case When i.ITEM_SIZE = 'M' Then o.QUANTITY * 1 End "SIZE_M_FABRIC_QNT", 
          Case When i.ITEM_SIZE = 'L' Then o.QUANTITY End "SIZE_L_ITEMS",
          Case When i.ITEM_SIZE = 'L' Then o.QUANTITY * 2 End "SIZE_L_FABRIC_QNT", 
          Case When i.ITEM_SIZE = 'XL' Then o.QUANTITY End "SIZE_XL_ITEMS",
          Case When i.ITEM_SIZE = 'XL' Then o.QUANTITY * 4 End "SIZE_XL_FABRIC_QNT"
From          items i
Left Join orders o ON(o.ITEM_ID = i.ITEM_ID)
Order By  i.ITEM_ID
```

```sql
-- Option 2.  -  PIVOT clause
SELECT    *
FROM    ( Select      i.ITEM_ID, i.ITEM_NAME, 
                    o.CUSTOMER_ID,
                    i.ITEM_SIZE, 
                    o.QUANTITY
          From        items i
          Left Join orders o ON(o.ITEM_ID = i.ITEM_ID)
          Order By  i.ITEM_ID
        )
  PIVOT ( Sum(QUANTITY) as "ITEMS", Sum(QUANTITY * Case  When ITEM_SIZE = 'S' Then 1
                                                         When ITEM_SIZE = 'M' Then 1
                                                         When ITEM_SIZE = 'L' Then 2
                                                         When ITEM_SIZE = 'XL' Then 4
                                                    End) as "FABRIC_QNT"
          FOR ITEM_SIZE IN ('S' as "SIZE_S", 'M' as "SIZE_M", 'L' as "SIZE_L", 'XL' as "SIZE_XL" )
        )
Order By ITEM_ID
```

Both of the above options results the same:

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
   ITEM_ID ITEM_NAME CUSTOMER_ID SIZE_S_ITEMS SIZE_S_FABRIC_QNT SIZE_M_ITEMS SIZE_M_FABRIC_QNT SIZE_L_ITEMS SIZE_L_FABRIC_QNT SIZE_XL_ITEMS SIZE_XL_FABRIC_QNT
---------- --------- ----------- ------------ ----------------- ------------ ----------------- ------------ ----------------- ------------- ------------------
         1 Name 1 S                                                                                                                                           
         2 Name 1 M           12                                        2000              2000                                                                
         3 Name 1 L                                                                                                                                           
         4 Name 1 XL                                                                                                                                          
         5 Name 2 S           11         2000              2000                                                                                               
         6 Name 2 M                                                                                                                                           
         7 Name 2 L                                                                                                                                           
         8 Name 2 XL          14                                                                                                       2000               8000
         9 Name 3 S                                                                                                                                           
        10 Name 3 M                                                                                                                                           
        11 Name 3 L           11                                                                       2000              4000                                 
        12 Name 3 XL                                                                                                                                            */
```